# Windows Vista: turn off UAC dimming

Tags: windows-vista, uac, sp2

I'm running Windows Vista HP 32-bit on my laptop right now (used to have Windows 7 Ultimate RC 32-bit). The thing is, I miss the fact that in Windows 7, [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) could be adjusted so that the whole screen doesn't dim when UAC activates.

Is there software or a tweak that I could use to stop the whole screen from dimming when UAC goes on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** (thanks grawity): From MS, [What are UAC settings?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-are-User-Account-Control-settings) Because the UAC dialog box isn't on the secure desktop with this setting, other programs might be able to interfere with the visual appearance of the dialog box. This is a small security risk if you already have a malicious program running on your computer.

**Windows Vista Business/Ultimate Users**

To get to the configuration screen for this, type in security to the start menu search box. You should see the **`Local Security Policy`** as the top search item.

In the Local Security Policy window, browse down to **`Local Policies \ Security Options`**

Over in the right hand part of the window, scroll down near the bottom and find the item titled **`“User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation”`**. Double-click on it to open it up, then change it to **`disabled`**.

At this point Secure Desktop should be disabled.

**Windows Vista Home Users**

You will need to open up **`regedit`** via the start menu search box. Browse down to this registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
```

Right-click in the right-hand pane and create a new **`32-bit DWORD value`** called **`PromptOnSecureDesktop`**, setting the value to **`0`**.

**Downloadable Registry Tweak**

Just download, extract, and double-click on the DisableSecureDesktop.reg file to enter the information into the registry. There’s also an included EnableSecureDesktop.reg file to put things back to the way they were.

[Download DisableSecureDesktop Registry Hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/DisableSecureDesktop.zip)

source: [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-user-account-control-uac-stop-blacking-out-the-screen-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: Perfect tweak! Not as annoying now.. heh =P

Comment: Remember that you don't just disable "dimming" this way - you disable the entire "Secure desktop" functionality in UAC. It's called "Secure desktop" not without a reason.